# Python pandas how to join two files to one and use sql?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

This is my code:

```
important panda as pd    
df1= pd.read_csv("efwfewfw.csv")    
df2= pdf.read_csv("efwefewf.csv")    
df3= pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=true)
```

sql_query = ?

Mission= i want to combine df1 and df2 to one file but without duplicates in terms of column title and row content.

Question one= in df3 i wrote ([ ]) what does that mean?

Question two= i wrote .drop_duplicates() what does this round bracket does?

question three= i did read something about an sql_query so that i can use in python panda sql commands in order to filter for certain things?
question four= why does my whole code not work, when i run it in python?

Answer (score 1):

you can two way: merge and append:

```
df1= pd.read_csv("efwfewfw.csv")    
df2= pdf.read_csv("efwefewf.csv") 
#1
both = df1.append(df2)
#2
both = pd.merge(df1, df2[['col1', 'col2']], on = ['col1'], how='left')
```